# Redshift Query for comparing current row to previous row - SQL query to Redshift Query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a table test with fields - A (ID), B (Flag). I need to add a new column - C (Result) in this table and it's value will be derived based on B (Flag) field. If flag is false then keep checking previous rows till we get flag as true and then take value of A (ID) field and populate it in C (Result) column. So C will have the last value of A with B field as True.

I have the query in SQL but when I try to use it in Redshift I get following errors.

1st Query Option:

```
    WITH 
    cte1 AS (
         SELECT A, SUM(B='T') OVER (ORDER BY A) group_no
         FROM test
    ),  
    cte2 AS (
         SELECT A, MIN(A) OVER (PARTITION BY group_no) previous_T
         FROM cte1
    )
    UPDATE test
    JOIN cte2 USING (A)
    SET test.C = cte2.previous_T;
```

I am getting errors in SUM and MIN function.

2nd Query Option:

```
    UPDATE test
    JOIN (
    SELECT A, 
       @tmp := CASE WHEN B='T' THEN A ELSE @tmp END C
    FROM test
    JOIN (SELECT @tmp:=0) init
    ORDER BY A
    ) data USING (A)
    SET test.C = data.C;
```

Getting error in temporary table.

I am new to SQL with no experience in Redshift, appreciate any help I get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I only have a few min but I think I can get you started.  Let’s stick to query #1.

SUM(B=‘T’) isn’t going to work in Redshift.  Look at the function DECODE() as it will allow you to switch how a column is generated based on another column.

It looks like you want to do a rolling SUM() so you will need a frame clause (likely “rows unbounded preceding”).

It’s not clear why you want SUM() of ids.  I’d think you would want MAX() as this will give you the highest preceding id.  Advise if I’m missing something.

I’d think you would want something like:

```
DECODE(B=‘T’, true, A, MAX(A) OVER (order by A rows unbounded preceding) as prev_id
```

But I don’t know your data or the process you are trying to implement.

As for the UPDATE I suggest you look at the Redshift docs.  This will look more like:

```
…
update test set c = cte.prev_id
from cte
where test.id = cte.id;
```

This assumes the id is unique and that I have half a clue what you are trying to do.